# Structuremap 3 constructor that accepts list of all registered types/instances

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap, constructor-injection, structuremap3

I have an object which expects an `IEnumerable<IPluginType>` as a parameter to it's constructor. I also have a line in my container configuration which adds all implementers of IPluginType:

```
x.Scan(s =>
{
    ...

    s.AddAllTypesOf<IPluginType>();
});
```

I've confirmed via container.WhatDoIHave() that the expected implementers are registered, but the IEnumerable is not being populated.

I guess I'm being a little optimistic thinking that Structuremap will know what I mean, how can I tell it?

Comment: What is the connection between `IPluginType` and the constructor? Do you mean a class has a constructor which takes `IEnumerable<IPluginType>`?

Comment: Sorry, @Rhumborl, the angular brackets obscured IPluginType in the first sentence. Clearer now?

Comment: If the `IPluginType`s are definitely registered as you say, structuremap does seem to resolve it correctly - https://dotnetfiddle.net/NpehG0

Comment: You're right @Rhumborl, it does just work with the set up that I've created - I was previously using an abstract type now I've moved this to an interface and it just works. Please provide your explanation as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `IPluginType`s are definitely registered in the `Container` as you say, StructureMap does resolve it correctly and pass one of each registered type into the `IEnumerable`. As you found, you need to use interfaces, not abstract types.

Here is a complete working example (or [as a dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Prx7Pm)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using StructureMap;

namespace StructureMapTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(s =>
                {
                    s.AssemblyContainingType<IPluginType>();
                    s.AddAllTypesOf<IPluginType>();
                });

                x.For<IMyType>().Use<MyType>();
            });

            var myType = container.GetInstance<IMyType>();
            myType.PrintPlugins();
        }
    }

    public interface IMyType
    {
        void PrintPlugins();
    }

    public class MyType : IMyType
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IPluginType> plugins;

        public MyType(IEnumerable<IPluginType> plugins)
        {
            this.plugins = plugins;
        }

        public void PrintPlugins()
        {
            foreach (var item in plugins)
            {
                item.DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IPluginType
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public class Plugin1 : IPluginType
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plugin1");
        }
    }

    public class Plugin2 : IPluginType
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plugin2");
        }
    }
}
```